# If even and odd numbers are equally likely, then why is the probability of getting an even number lesser then probability of getting an odd number?

Tags: probability

Let $P(n) = 2^{-n}$ denote the probability of obtaining a positive number n.
Sample space is the set of all positive numbers.
To calculate the probability of obtaining an even number, we'll do summation over infinite GP. Similarly, we'll do it to determine the probability of obtaining an odd number.

Here are the results that were obtained.

$P(Even\ number) = 1/3$
$P(Odd\ number) = 2/3$

My doubt is that if both even and odd numbers equally likely, then why is there a difference in the probabilities of their occurrence? Shouldn't it be 1/2 for both cases?

Comment: Why do you claim that “even and odd numbers equally likely”? You have proved that they are not!

Comment: What does "equally likely" mean?  You have a fixed distribution which you chose for whatever reason, which has no reason to respect that rule.

Comment: @lulu, So as per the distribution chosen, the results might vary?

Comment: Of course!  your distribution could be $P(1)=x$, $P(2)=1-x$.   for any $x\in [0,1]$ and $P(n)=0$ for all $n>2$.

Comment: @lulu, thank you! Got it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, Got it sir. I had misconception which got cleared. Thanks!

Comment: You can only assume that even and odd numbers have the same chance of appearing if you have no information. For example, the events: 1) I will win the lottery and 2) I will not win the lottery are not equally likely.

Comment: I heard there are many numbers larger than 6, so why don't any of them ever show up when I roll a die?

Comment: @MJD, it's because the dice has digit only from 1 to 6 inclusively. Hence, under no circumstances, a digit greater then 6 can appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of getting $1$ is $2^{-1}=1/2$.

The probability of getting $3$ is $2^{-3}=1/8$.

The probability of getting $5$ is $2^{-5}=1/32$.

Since probabilities are always positive and they must sum to one, it is already clear without computing the entire sum that the probability of getting an odd number is greater than $1/2$ and hence must be greater than the probability of getting an even number.